# Graphics library to draw images to screen for python

Tags: python, graphics, libraries

I would like to know if there is a good graphics library for python that will allow me to write a console/terminal application in which I can draw images and or shapes similar to libraries that are available in C++. My applications will be developed for linux primarily but will likely also be made available for windows but it ultimately not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I already used the following libraries that offer this type of resource:

- Tkinter
- wxPython (https://www.wxpython.org/) - you can use it to draw shapes or images and there are a lot of built ins resources to create GUI
- Pygame (https://www.pygame.org/news) - it's very useful to do physics simulations, you can use built in function to draw circles, blit images into the screen, access keys inputs, etc.
- Matplotlib (https://matplotlib.org/) - this is good to mathematical purposes to draw graphs, but you can animate the graphs too

The Pygame help and docs is not user friendly (my think), but the learning curve is fast.